# How can i count G+C, GC%

Tags: perl

I have a perl script that counts ATGC in every 0-200 basepairs upto 1000 i.e 0-200, 1-201, 2-202, upto 1000. I also want to count G+C bases in these 0-200, 1-201...upto 1000 and also to calculate GC% in these regions. How can i do this.

Perl script is:

```
#! perl -slw
use strict;

my $dna = do{ local $/; <DATA> };
$dna =~ tr[\n][]d;

my %counts;
++$counts{ substr $dna, $_, 1 } for 0 .. 199;

for my $offset ( 0 .. length( $dna )-200 ) {
    printf "range: %d .. %d A:%d C:%d G:%d T:%d\n", $offset, $offset+199, @counts{ qw[ A C G T ] };
    --$counts{ substr $dna, $offset, 1 };
    ++$counts{ substr $dna, $offset+200, 1 };
}

__DATA__
TGCCATCGCGCCAGGAGGGAAGACCAGTTGCTCTGGGTAAATCAGCCGTGAGCGTATCTGTCCCTCTTATAATTAGGAGTTTAAACTCTACGATGTTACC
ATCCTTGAATCAGGTATATACCGCACTGAAACATCGTCGGCTTTGGGCTCATTCGCTACCCTGTCGCTGATATGCGATCTATTCTACATATGCGGGGCCA
CCCAATGTCGATTGTCATGAGGAGGGGGTCATAACGACTCACTATAGGACCAGCACGTCCGGTTGCGCTGAGTAAAATAGAGCTACAAAAGACACAGTAC
TCCAAGATGTAAAGGGGAAGACGGGACCTGGGTCGGGGGCGCAACTTCACTGAGCTTTTAACCTTGCGCGCATGCGAGAGCCTTTCCGCTTAGGAAATGC
TGTAAGATCAAGTGGTAGGACTATTGAGAGGTCTTACCTTGCCGCAGCAACGTGGACGGCGACCGGATAATTTAAGGCCGACATTCAATATAGAATGTCA
GGGAGCAGAACTGTATCCCAAATGCTAGTTGTAGGTGTACGAGCGCACCTGGGGACCTATCGCTCCGACGGGGTCTGCGTAGCCCATACATCCTGCCAGC
ACTGGGGCTATTGAACGGTCAATCCGTAATGTACTCGCTGAATGCTCAGGGATTCCTTAATCTTTGAGCACGCGGCTTCTCTCACTTTTCTCACGTCAAC
CCTGACTCATAACGGAGTTCGGCAGTCCCGGAACGGCTTATAGAAGCAATGCCTGAGTAGATAGCGTCAGGGATCGGCCCTACGTCGAGTCCAGTACGCC
ATTGGATGGAGGTCTCAGCCGTCGGTGGAGTGCGGCTCCACCCCCACATGAACGAGGTTGTTCCTGACCACCCCTGAAACTGTGAGAACCATTGTGTCGA
AACCAAGAGGCTTGCGTCGCGCTATAGGTCGATTGCCCCCTAGTTTCCCTATATTGAACGTGTTTCCATTAAAGACTCTCGGTAAATCTCACGTATTGCA
```

output:

```
C:\test>junk77
range: 0 .. 199 A:46 C:51 G:47 T:56
range: 1 .. 200 A:46 C:52 G:47 T:55
range: 2 .. 201 A:46 C:53 G:46 T:55
range: 3 .. 202 A:46 C:53 G:46 T:55
range: 4 .. 203 A:47 C:52 G:46 T:55
range: 5 .. 204 A:47 C:52 G:46 T:55
range: 6 .. 205 A:47 C:52 G:46 T:55
range: 7 .. 206 A:47 C:51 G:47 T:55
range: 8 .. 207 A:47 C:51 G:46 T:56
range: 9 .. 208 A:47 C:51 G:46 T:56
range: 10 .. 209 A:47 C:51 G:46 T:56
range: 11 .. 210 A:48 C:50 G:46 T:56
range: 12 .. 211 A:48 C:49 G:46 T:57
range: 13 .. 212 A:47 C:49 G:46 T:58
range: 14 .. 213 A:47 C:49 G:46 T:58
range: 15 .. 214 A:47 C:49 G:45 T:59
range: 16 .. 215 A:46 C:50 G:45 T:59
range: 17 .. 216 A:47 C:50 G:44 T:59
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As phrased, your question is trivially simple; makes me wonder if I'm missing something.

Replace your print with:

```
    printf "range: %d .. %d A:%d C:%d G:%d T:%d G+C:%d GC%%:%.1f\n", $offset, $offset+199, @counts{ qw[ A C G T ] }, $counts{'G'}+$counts{'C'}, ($counts{'G'}+$counts{'C'})/200*100;
```

Comment: It works, but there is another problem (1) it produces output that starts counting ranging from 290-489 not from 0-199. I don't know where is the problem. (2) And if we want to print only that regions of output which have GC% more than 50% then how can we do that.

Comment: (1) the code you posted doesn't do that; what's different about the code you are running now?  (2) put an if around the printf statement: `if ( $counts{'G'}+$counts{'C'} > 100 ) { printf ...; }`